# Why is my php not returning proper json? ("expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32")

Tags: php, json, encoding

I am having trouble using Alamofire in iOS because because my php seems to not be returning valid json. I have added the header "header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");" before encoding array but it still does not work. If it matters some columns in my database table are encoding using utf8mb4_unicode_ci. **Here is my php:**

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","hide","hide","hide");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Business";

    if($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }

        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }

    mysqli_close($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Unformatted json:**

```
[{"business_id":"0","imageURL":"imageUrl","shortDescription":"shortDescription","longDescription":"longDescription","price":"price","specialText":"specialText","order_rank":"1"}]
```

**Here is formatted json specifying error:**

[image]

Comment: If your table's charset is `utf8mb4`, you need to set `mysqli_set_charset('utf8mb4')` and not `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')`

Comment: Is charset collation? If so my "Collation" is latin1_swedish_ci :S

Comment: Found out that it is. I now changed my table collation (charset) to utf8_general_ci and am now going to see if things are any better :S

Comment: Changing table charset to utf8 didn't fix it :( Now changed to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Collation is not charset. Charset is how the symbols are decoded, and collation is how letters are compared (weighted) one to another. Collation is used for alphabetic ordering, and it serves as a lookup table for MySQL so it knows how to order accented letters etc. Table charset should be `utf8` and connection charset should be `utf8`. When `json_encode` fails, you can always check what happened with `json_last_error_msg()` and it would be ok if you printed the array you're encoding so you can spot exactly which character is causing problems.

Comment: I'm not sure if it does fail though. The data is still echoed, but apparently it isn't as json :S

Comment: I think I figured out my problem. I was assuming that my json array was a json object (which most tutorials are examples of).